# ArcScene - Multipatch from TIFF DEM?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene

Our team is trying to do a Line of Sight analysis and we couldn't figure out what when we run it, the resulting lines drape along the surface until we read the [How Ling of Sight Works](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/how-line-of-sight-works.htm)

This question is similar to [3D Analyst Line of Sight: what am I doing wrong?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102581/3d-analyst-line-of-sight-what-am-i-doing-wrong) and was never answered.

We have a TIFF DEM, we have points that have Z values, and the construct sight lines are similar to what we need. However, how can we have our TIFF DEM act as our Multipatch? There are no obstructions in our study other than the terrain itself.